# What is the posterior in-sample vs the posterior out-of-sample?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, out-of-sample, in-sample

I'm watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlzVlqVzeD8&t=1157s) on Bayesian modelling for the stock market by Thomas Wiecki, Thomas has a slide with two posterior distribution over the mean parameter in his stock return model. Around 18:26 we see this slide:

[image: this slide]

The phrase “in-sample” and “out-of-sample” *in regard to a posterior distribution*, both in regard to the same latent variable, confuses me.

If one wants to look at the latent variables, the way I understand it, one can:

- Look at the *prior* of a latent variable, which is designed by the user.
- Look at the *posterior* of a latent variable, which one can obtain after observing some data.

At no point in the Bayesian workflow does an “out-of-sample” vs “in-sample posterior” come up, just posterior vs prior.

**Question**: What does “in-sample posterior” vs “out-of-sample posterior” mean?

Comment: I haven't watched the video, but I'd imagine he is referring to a posterior distribution estimated under training data (in-sample in finance") and test data (out-of-sample).

Comment: @Forgottenscience One might think, but in both cases one would normally use the same posterior distribution of a latent variable for in-sample and out-of-sample predictions and in his presentation they are clearly different. Look at the image of the slide I posted if you haven't already. Updating the posterior using out-of-sample data would be inappropriate, otherwise it would be called in-sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained earlier in the talk, from around 3:12 ([link](https://youtu.be/LlzVlqVzeD8?t=201)).

[image]

Quantopian users train financial models on historical data ("in-sample period"), and test them on new data ("out-of-sample period"). Due to overfitting, the models usually do better on the in-sample data.

The speaker's job is to evaluate how well these financial models perform, by considering both their in-sample and out-of-sample performance. He *fits a model to evaluate the performance data generated by the users' models*. This is where the terminology gets confusing!